# Mongodb 3.4 - What's the correct way to add replicas to a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

In the documentation I've found two ways to add replicas to a member:

[rs.add()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/#pass-a-hostname-string-to-rs-add)

```
rs.add('mongodb0.example.net:27017')
```

[sh.addShard()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#add-shards-to-the-cluster)

```
sh.addShard( "rs1/mongodb0.example.net:27017" )
```

So, to check if I understand:  Are this staments true?

- rs.add() is used to add extra replicas of a member to it's replica set. Can be used for config servers and shards.
- sh.addShard() is the specific method to add shards to the cluster. But for convenience can also be used to add replicas to a shard's replicaSet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> > rs.add() is used to add extra replicas of a member to it's replica set. Can be used for config servers and shards.

-

> rs.add() is used to add extra replicas of a member to it's replica set

The above statement is correct. But to be more precise, I'll rephrase it as to "add extra members to the current Primary's replica set".

> Can be used for config servers

Yes, if you are using  [Replica Set Config Server](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/#csrs) - as oppossed three mirrored config servers (SCCC) in MongoDB 3.2, or you are using MongoDB 3.4.

> and shards

This is not correct. Shard is a logical member of a cluster, which - by itself - can be a replica set or a standalone (standalones are recommended for test / development purposes only). You can not added shard to a cluster using the `rs` shell hellper.

> > sh.addShard() is the specific method to add shards to the cluster. But for convenience can also be used to add replicas to a shard's replicaSet.

-

> sh.addShard() is the specific method to add shards to the cluster.

Correct

> But for convenience can also be used to add replicas to a shard's replicaSet.

Not true. `addShard`, as it's name implies is used to add shard to clusters and not members (what you refer as a replicas) to a set. As mentioned, a shard can be a standalone or a replica set. In that latter case the `addShard` argument must be a the replica set name (`rs1`) followed by '/'. followed by replica set seed member(s). Putting it all together: `"rs1/mongodb0.example.net:27017"`

You - at least - have to initialize a replica set before you add it as a shard to a clusters. You can always add (or remove) members from that replica set after it has joined a cluster as a shard.